# Python OpenCV imshow Expected mat Argument

Tags: python, opencv, imagegrab

I'm trying to write a program that shows a specific position on a given window. When I run the code OpenCV gives me an error message telling me unexpected type for argument mat. I have no idea what's wrong because when I use the position value in the following code it works fine. Please be nice as I'm fairly new to OpenCV.

Code:

```
#Imports
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32gui


#Assign Tesseract and other Variables
winList = []
toplist = []
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
lH = 33
lW = 20

#Window Handle Object
def enum_win(hwnd, result):

    winText = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)

    winList.append((hwnd, winText))

win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_win, toplist)


typeHwnd = 0

#Find Window Handle
for (hwnd, winText) in winList:

    if winText == "Program WinText Name Here":
        typeHwnd = hwnd
if typeHwnd == 0:
    print("Oops no Window Found")


while True:
    position = win32gui.GetWindowRect(typeHwnd)

    mid = (position[0] + (position[0] + position[2]))/2

    sPos = [int(mid)-267, position[1] + 295, lW, lH]

    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=sPos)
    screenshot = np.array(screenshot)

    cv2.imshow("Screen", screenshot)
    key = cv2.waitKey(25)

print(position)
print(mid)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/Typing Bot/main.py", line 47, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Screen", screenshot)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

System Specifications:

I am running Windows 10 64 bit and Python 3 with the most recent version of all the imported modules installed.

Comment: first check what you have in variable - `print(screenshot)`, `print(type(screenshot))`

Comment: That returns tuple. So instead of an array I need sPos to be a tuple.

Comment: Even if I make sPos a tuple instead of an array it gives me that same error.

Comment: I asked of `screenshot`, not `sPos`. `screenshot` in `imshow` has to be `numpy array` - and this is in your error message. And it doesn't mater if your `sPos` is tuple or list.

Comment: BTW: shorter `mid = position[0] + position[2]//2`

Comment: well, you may have problem with `sPos` in `grab` - it has to be `[x1, y1, x2, y2]` but it seems you use `[x, y, width, height]`

Comment: Screenshot is numpy.ndarray, and thanks for the shorter mid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error shows problem with `array` in `imshow` but your problem starts with `sPos` in `grab`.

`grab` needs `bbox` which means `[x1, y1, x2, y2]` but you use `[x, y, width, height]` and this starts problem because `grab` returns image with size `(0,0)` and `np.array()` can't convert it so it returns `pillow image` instead of `numpy array` and then `imshow` gets `pillow image` instead of `numpy array` and it can't display it.

---

You have to use `[x, y, x+width, y+height]`

---

Minimal working example - with wrong and correct `pos`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import PIL.ImageGrab

x = 100
y = 100
w = 50 
h = 50 

pos = [x, y, w, h]      # wrong 
#pos = [x, y, x+w, y+h]  # correct 

print('bbox:', pos)
print('---')

img = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(pos)
print('img:', img)
print('type(img):', type(img))
print('img.size:', img.size)
print('---')

arr = np.array(img)
print('arr:', arr)
print('type(arr):', type(arr))
print('arr.size:', arr.size)
print('arr.shape:', arr.shape)
print('---')

cv2.imshow('test', arr)

print('Press ESC to exit')
while cv2.waitKey(100) != 27:
    pass
```